# Why is "yo me quedo en casa" instead of "yo quedo en casa"?

Tags: conjugación, reflexivos, verbo-pronominal

So I understand that [it's "me quedo" instead of "yo quedo"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20423/5481) because the "yo" is omitted. Just like everything else in Spanish, the verb tense gives away what the pronoun is.

Why is it then "yo **me** quedo" instead of just "yo quedo"?

Comment: Because the action falls on the person who does it.

Comment: At first I thought that the answers to your previous question were relevant here, but now I understand that here you specifically ask about the use of "me" while in the other one is more about person used for the conjugation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"[Quedar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=UloraJw)" is an intransitive verb, which can also be use as pronominal (quedar(**se**)).

This [pronominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb) use means roughly that their subjects are acting upon themselves (I do this action upon myself).

> Hoy [nosotros] nos quedamos en casa.

"We" receive the action of staying at home.

Pronominal verbs must be conjugated with a reflexive pronoun (Yo **me** quedo; Nosotros **nos** quedamos).

Pronominal verbs fall into three major classes based on their meaning:

- reflexive: Yo **me** lavo (a mi mismo)
- idiomatic (reflexive actions per se): Yo **me** divierto.
- reciprocal: Ellos **se** besan. Las niñas **se** peinan (one to another. This one could actually be reflexive too. Each girl does her own hair, as opposed to each girl doing each other's hair).

Compare

> Yo **me** lavo (a mi mismo ==> reflexive)

With

> Yo lavo los platos

Quedar(se) is a little bit tricky because it is an intrasitive verb, which can be used as *pronominal*. It does not literally say "I place myself at home", but the agent of the action is simultaneously the patient, which is what a reflexive verb implies.

Comment: I'd like to add to Diego's excellent answer that "yo quedo" is also possible, though less usual and different from "yo me quedo". "Yo quedo" could be used for a competition in which different participants are excluded and the speaker remains or "survives" (not by his/her own free will, but upon somebody else's decision).

Comment: I agree completely and to add to @Gustavson comment there's the common sentence **(Yo) Quedo atento** to express that _I'll be expecting something_

Comment: @DGaleano and one more: _Quedo contigo a las diez_ meaning "I will meet you at ten o'clock". Though it is more natural to say _quedamos_.

Answer (score 1):

***quedar***

means "be," while

***quedarse***

means "stay, remain."  Linguée has some good examples [(1)](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=quedar), [(2)](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=quedarse):

> El museo **queda** lejos del hotel.  *The museum is a long way from the hotel.*
>
> **Nos quedamos** en el hotel tres días.  *We stayed at the hotel for three days.*
>
> Los niños no pudieron **quedarse** quietos justo antes del recreo.  *The children could not stay still just before recess.*
>
> **Me quedé** en casa para cuidar al gato.  *I remained at home to take care of the cat.*